# Javascript Contact form with Hugo

Tags: javascript, blogs, hugo

For the long time I used to embed a javascript **contact form** into my hugo page with following method:

```
+++
title= "any title"
date= "date"
customjs = "https://www.123formbuilder.com/embed/5383850.js"
+++

<script type="text/javascript" defer src="//www.123formbuilder.com/embed/5383850.js" data-role="form" data-default-width="650px">
        </script>
```

it supposed to load a contact form into my hugo page. 
But recently i've found that it's no longer working. I'm using **Hugo 0.68.3 extended**.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: can you tell where you found the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

solved after editing config.toml file changes to goldmark.